# Center textbox in a stretched tab control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, tabcontrol

I am making a multi-tab application in WPF, and I want to make a textbox centered horizontally in the tab's grid. The tab control is currently stretched to fit the window size, so if the window is resized/maximized, the app will change size as well. If I press the "center horizontally" button in the designer, it puts the textbox way off to the right. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the XAML code for the app so far:

```
<Window x:Class="GUI_Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GUI_Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="524" Width="996.432">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
            <TabItem x:Name="Home" Header="Home" Width="150">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem x:Name="Dictionary" Header="Dictionary" Width="150">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem x:Name="Search" Header="Search" Height="20" Width="150">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="23" Margin="524,105,204,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250"/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem x:Name="About" Header="About" Height="20" Width="150">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I am focused on the "Search" tab at this moment. The textbox (and any other elements, for that matter) also need to move when the window is expanded, so I can't just calculate the midpoints and set the dimensions. I would do something like `MarginLeft = MainWindow.getWidth/2` or something similar but there is neither a `MarginLeft` nor a `MainWindow` that has any editable properties.
I also tried making the grid in the tab a differend layout, but it won't allow me to.

Comment: Please show us some code. see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you. It  has been edited. Sorry, I'm not very fluent in the rules of StackOverflow yet :)

Comment: Remove the margin from the TextBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right and you want to horizontally centralize the `TextBox` on the `Grid`, all you have to to is set `HorizontalAlignment` to `Center` and remove the `Margin` on both left and right side (first and third numbers), like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="23" Margin="0,105,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250"/>
```

Emphasis on `Margin="0,105,0,0"`, that is what's different from your code.

If you want to centralize it vertically too, just set `VerticalAlignment` to `Center` and completely remove `Margin` (or set it to zero).

Comment: That worked, thanks. I see where the issues arise, with the conflict of interests.